# Allow/Deny getUserMedia button

Tags: vline

I would like to enable user to see their self-view right after they log on, which will also require them to click the allow button on the browser for getUserMedia. This way they will be ready to receive a call without having to click the allow camera button each time they receive a call.

Does vline support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call the [`vline.Client.getLocalStream`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client#getLocalStream) method to get the local video stream before making a call.

An example where this is actually used can be found in the [vline-room-example](https://github.com/vline/vline-room-example/blob/master/source/index.html).